# Why is my event.soptPropagation in React not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working in React and using MUI components.  The problem I'm running into is that when I click the subscribe Button, the click event for the CardActionArea component is running as well.  I understand that this is because of propagation/bubbling, but I can't figure out how to fix it from what I've found online.  I'm hoping someone here can help me with a solution.

```
function subscribeClick(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("button was clicked");
}

function cardClick() {
    console.log("card was clicked");
}
```

Above is the code for the functions

```
return (
    <Card variant="outlined" className="card-item" sx={{ width: 500, verticalAlign: 'top' }} style={{ display: 'inline-block', borderRadius: '0', verticalAlign: 'top' }}>

        <CardActionArea component={RouterLink} to={'./Details/' + props.reportName} onClick={cardClick}>
            <CardContent className='card-content' style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                <h2 style={{ display: "inline-block" }} className='card-header'>{props.reportName}</h2>
                <Button onClick={subscribeClick} variant="contained">Subscribe</Button>
            </CardContent>
        </CardActionArea>

        <CardActions style={{ justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
            {StatusBars}
        </CardActions>

    </Card>
);
```

There is the code for the components that call those functions.

I have tried passing in the event to the subscribeClick function in the onClick of the button by using an arrow function, I've tried calling subscribeClick using this.subscribeClick, as well as various different ways of calling the function from Buttons onClick.  I can't figure out why it is still bubbling up to the cardClick function.

Comment: Can you create reproducible version using sandbox?

Comment: Do you mean that when you click on the button, it's still taking you to /details page?

Comment: I recommend you use `event.preventDefault()`. I recently covered event cancellation in a (not react specific) [blog post](https://dev.to/teetotum/a-clean-approach-to-dom-event-cancellation-11m3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not the `CardActionArea` component or your functions that you have implemented.

The problem is with the `Link` component.

When you click on a `Link` component, and by extension what's inside it as well, it will simply redirect you to the page.

Calling `event.stopPropagation()` here only stops the propagation of the `onClick` event, but does not stop the default behaviour of the `Link` component.

What you're missing here is `event.preventDefault()` inside of your button function, which prevents the default behaviour of the `Link` component.

```
function subscribeClick(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopPropagation();
   console.log("button was clicked");
}
```

If you also wish to disable the ripple effect of the `CardActionArea` component when clicking on "Subscribe", you should add the following to your button:

```
onMouseDown={(event) => { event.stopPropagation() }}
```

Comment: Glad this helped you! Don't forget to mark this as the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

also if you want to disable the ripple effect when click on the subscribe button you can do something like this:

```
import { Card, CardActionArea, CardContent, Button, CardActions } from '@mui/material'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useState } from 'react'
const Test = () => {
  const [disableRipple, setDisableRipple] = useState(false)
  const cardClick = () => console.log('clicked card')
  const subscribeClick = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('subscribe')
  }

  const handleEnter = () => {
    setDisableRipple(true)
  }
  const handleLeave = () => {
    setDisableRipple(false)
  }

  return (
    <Card variant="outlined" className="card-item" sx={{ width: 500, verticalAlign: 'top' }}>
      <CardActionArea
        component={Link}
        to="./Details/reportName"
        onClick={cardClick}
        disableRipple={disableRipple}
      >
        <CardContent
          className="card-content"
          style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}
        >
          <h2 className="card-header">reportName</h2>
          <Button
            onClick={subscribeClick}
            variant="contained"
            onMouseEnter={handleEnter}
            onMouseLeave={handleLeave}
          >
            Subscribe
          </Button>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>

      <CardActions style={{ justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>StatusBars</CardActions>
    </Card>
  )
}

export default Test
```